# OpenOffice macro counter help please

Tags: python, macros, counter, openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet in OpenOffice that I need to add a macro into that basically just counts up to a certain number.  I prefer to use Python as I am most familiar with it, but I have no experience with applying that to macros in OpenOffice.

This code works fine in the Python GUI:

---

```
import time

a = 0
b = 500

while a < b:
    a = a + 1
    print(a)
    time.sleep(2)
```

---

The spreadsheet has a list of items numbered 1-50.  Selection is based on the number entered into cell E5.  I would like the macro to "count" in cell E5 so that each item is cycled through the selection formulas.

I believe I can code what I need to, but how do I get Python code to work in OpenOffice Calc spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
Sub Main

Dim oDoc As Object
Dim oSheet As Object

oDoc=ThisComponent
oSheet=oDoc.Sheets.getByName("Sheet1")
oCell=oSheet.getCellRangeByName("d20")
a=0

Do
a=a+1
oCell.SetString(a)
Wait 2500
Loop While a < 10

End Sub
```